# MySQL: Who are today "on" between 2 different dates

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, between

I have a Mysql problem. (I use PHP with it).

For example I have this kind of database:

Name  | Started and | will end
Jason | 2009-12-17 | 2009-12-24
Ericke  | 2009-12-12 | 2009-12-30
Maria | 2010-01-02 | 2010-01-10

With mysql (or php) question I would like to get the names of people, which are "on" right now (2009-12-19).

The answer should be:
Jason 
Ericke

Thank you for your great help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about a query in which you compare dates ?

Something like this, I suppose, should do :

```
select name
from your_table
where started <= curdate() 
    and will_end >= curdate()
```

Notes :

- You'll need to adjust the table and columns names, of course
- and maybe you'll want to use `>` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=` ; depends on your data.
- I use the [`curdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function, which gets the date of the current day -- I like it better than injecting the date into the query using some PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN `startdate` AND `enddate`
```